# Adding data attribute to slim with no value

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I have the html `<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">` from https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/topbar.html. But I'm not sure how this converts to slim.

`nav class="top-bar" role="navigation" data-topbar`

This causes problems because data-topbar has no value.

`nav class="top-bar" role="navigation" data-topbar=''`

This is valid slim but it adds the ='' which I don't want. Is there any way to add this attribute with no value in slim?

Comment: I'm un-sure why you need data attribute if you don't need a value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you write like this:

```
nav class="top-bar" role="navigation" data-topbar
```

You will get this:

```
<nav class="top-bar" role="navigation">data-topbar</nav>
```

If you write like this:

```
nav(class="top-bar" role="navigation" data-topbar)
```

When you `inspect` code you will see

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation"></nav>
```

But when you copy the dom or view source code you will get this one (like every [boolean attributes](http://w3c.github.io/html/infrastructure.html#sec-boolean-attributes))

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar="" role="navigation"></nav>
```